# New smartphones that are unlocked

Tags: cellphones, terminology

What does "Unlocked Worldwide (Only T-Mobile/Mint/Metro USA Market)" mean in this [link (on Amazon Canada)](https://www.amazon.ca/gp/aw/d/B0C2JPWX94/ref=ox_sc_act_image_1?smid=A10N22PZ56W0EE&psc=1)? And since the mobile product in question is only unlocked for T-Mobile/Mint/Metro USA Market", can't it be used in countries like Canada or Mexico? I thought every new mobile phone is unlocked. Or maybe I am wrong about it. I am not tech savvy, so I apologize if the question sounds "stupid". Thank you in advance!

Comment: if you're looking at 'grey imports' try the UK market, where carriers are no longer allowed to lock phones at all.

Comment: That's true for Canadian carriers as well, although I'm sure it doesn't apply to a random seller online

Comment: It's a marketing claim from a 3rd party seller on Amazon.   It's probably complete nonsense.  If you didn't know, [the vast majority of Amazon listings are 3rd party sellers](https://nymag.com/intelligencer/2023/01/why-does-it-feel-like-amazon-is-making-itself-worse.html), making Amazon very similar to eBay.  Prime is nice, but you take your chances with the items.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica You sure do, e.g. [Lawsuit: Amazon sold eclipse glasses that cause “permanent blindness”](https://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2017/08/lawsuit-amazon-sold-eclipse-glasses-that-cause-permanent-blindness/)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Unlocked Worldwide

This means that when connected to cellular networks in countries other than the US you can put in any SIM card that will work in that country

> (Only T-Mobile/Mint/Metro USA Market)

This means that if you're connected to a US network you must use a SIM from one of those networks (which are basically all the same company anyway).

It means it was likely sold by T-Mobile at a discount, so locked to its networks, but has been unlocked to work outside of the US on any company's network.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150640/discussion-on-answer-by-midavalo-new-smartphones-that-are-unlocked); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 11):

The product description is more clear (formatting is mine):

> - USA Market Only Works on Tmobile / Mint / Metro PCS
> - Unlocked Worldwide GSM 5G + 4G LTE PHONE

I.e. from my understanding, it's locked on the USA market, but not outside. But I don't have any experience with that kind of BS, personally I only buy 100% unlocked. And if all customers were doing that, we wouldn't have that discussion.